# Difference between 'in the wild' and 'in the wilderness'?

Tags: nouns, expression-choice

In

> I once saw a tiger in the wild.

'in the wild' sounds like an existing collocation. How about 'in the wilderness'?

Comment: "In the wild" would mean "not in captivity".  For instance, though we don't have wild tigers hereabouts, it's by no means unusual to have bears and mountain lions visiting populated areas.  As for instance http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/08/24/mountain-lion-invades-ren_n_1829222.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am under the impression that 'in the wild' is a kind of state – 'roaming free' rather than 'in a cage' – qualifying the tiger and only it, whereas 'in the wilderness' is a place, where both the tiger and I were at the time.

Comment: Why did you post this answer? I don't think this post answers the question. What does "cage" and "place" have to do with the **wild** and **wilderness**? Do you mean *in the wild* can't mean a place?

Comment: That was a very good answer!  The only caveat would be that *sometimes* "wild" may be used as a synonym for "wilderness", and one must judge whether this is the case or not from context.

Comment: If I too had been 'in the wild', then I would have been 'au naturel', wouldn't I?!

Comment: @HotLicks: so, can a person be 'in the wild', meaning 'in the wilderness'?

Comment: @user58319 - It's a little difficult to define when using "wild" to mean wilderness would be idiomatic.  One case might be "I was hunting in the wilds of West Virginia", but note that in that case "wilds" is idiomatic, not "wild".  The singular "wild" tends to denote the general concept of "wilderness", rather than a specific instance.

Answer (score 2):

"Wilderness" refers to a place primarily uninhabited by humans, one that is not disturbed by civilization.  It refers to the the land, the environment. It can be a noun or an adjective.

examples: 
(noun) When you are alone in the wilderness, you cannot ignore the sound of your own thoughts.

(adjective) Wilderness camping takes careful preparation.

"In the wild" is the opposite of "in captivity". It is often used to describe an animal that is usually seen in captivity to emphasize that it was in its natural habitat.